# XPath string to select a specific node with specific value c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I want to select a node where inner text of `cat` is 'PG' using XPath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Students>
    <student>
        <name>Talha</name>
        <cat>PG</cat>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>irfan</name>
        <cat>UG</cat>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Ali</name>
        <cat>PG</cat>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Umer</name>
        <cat>UG</cat>
    </student>
</Students>
```

Code which I tried is this

```
XmlElement xmldoc = (XmlElement)doc.DocumentElement
    .SelectSingleNode("/Students/student/*[*[local-name()='cat']='PG']");
```

Comment: What's with the `local-name()` call? That's suspicious. You don't need that unless your actual XML has namespaces, and *even then* you don't really need it. So... does your actual XML have namespaces? If yes, show your actual XML. If not, get rid of `local-name()`.

Answer (score 1):

To select all the `student` nodes which sub-elements `cat` have the value 'PG' use this XPath expression

```
/Students/student[cat='PG']
```

To only get the first one use

```
/Students/student[cat='PG'][1]
```

So in the syntax of C# use

```
XmlElement xmldoc = (XmlElement)doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Students/student[cat='PG'][1]");
```

Comment: SelectSingleNode will only select a single node. No need for [1], right?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Yes. I only added that to emphasize that it's the first node of the two to be selected.